# How to update text inside li element?

Tags: javascript

The below code runs every time I select an option from a dropdown, however I do not want to append the li elements every time. Instead I'd just like to update the text the second time around.

```
function buildDem(i) {
    d3.json(url).then(function(data) {
        var id = data.metadata[i].id
        var ethnicity = data.metadata[i].ethnicity
        var gender = data.metadata[i].gender
        var age = data.metadata[i].age
        var location = data.metadata[i].location
        var bbtype = data.metadata[i].bbtype
        var wfreq = data.metadata[i].wfreq

        var selectMetabody = d3.select("#sample-metadata")
        var appendUnorderedlist = selectMetabody.append("ul")
        var appendListelements = appendUnorderedlist.append("li")
        var appendText = appendListelements.text("ID: " + id)
        var appendListelements = appendUnorderedlist.append("li")
        var appendText = appendListelements.text("Ethnicity: " + ethnicity)
        var appendListelements = appendUnorderedlist.append("li")
        var appendText = appendListelements.text("Gender: " + gender)
        var appendListelements = appendUnorderedlist.append("li")
        var appendText = appendListelements.text("Age: " + age)
        var appendListelements = appendUnorderedlist.append("li")
        var appendText = appendListelements.text("Location: " + location)
        var appendListelements = appendUnorderedlist.append("li")
        var appendText = appendListelements.text("BBtype: " + bbtype)
        var appendListelements = appendUnorderedlist.append("li")
        var appendText = appendListelements.text("Wfreq: " + wfreq)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful to use one powerful d3 function and perhaps also a structural convention:

1 (the function). In v5, the function `selection.join(enter[, update][, exit])` can help manage the addition, modification and removal of SVG Elements that are data bound. The [d3 docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/v1.4.1/README.md#selection_join) and this [introduction from M. Bostock himself](https://observablehq.com/@d3/selection-join) mercifully make sense of this approach.

2 (the convention). It may be that you want two separate your data collection/parsing and the rest of your code. You'd also want to separate the "rest of your code" into an initialization stage for one-time appending and update stage for dynamic element control.

Something like this:

```
// Init variables
let data = [];
let url = 'thisdataurl';

// Get data
d3.json(url, () => {
  // Parse data
}).then(d => {
  // Define data
  data = d;
  // Call vis building code
  initVis();
}).catch(err => console.error(err));

// Init vis
function initVis() {
  // Do all the building that needs to be done once

  // Move on to update vis code
  updateVis();
}

// Update vis
function updateVis() {
  // Place your enter/update/exit pattern (`d3.join`)
}

// Add some listener to your select button that when clicked calls 
//   a function that updates the url, fetches a new json from that new 
//   url, replaces the old data with new, and finally calls updateVis()
```

I often place a `wrangleData()` method in there when I'm just filtering the same data, and there are of course other strategies for managing complexity if the code is lengthened and linked to other visualizations. Good luck with this one!